Symmetric product basis in $L^2$
Consider an ON-basis on $L^2([a,b])$, $\{\phi_n\}_n$. Then we know that $\{\phi_n\otimes \phi_m\}_{m,n}$ is a basis for $L^2([a,b]\times [a,b])$.
What can be said about the closed linear span $V$ of the (ON) sequence  $\{\phi_n\otimes \phi_n\}_{n}$? Obviously any element in $V$ must be a symmetric function in  $L^2([a,b]\times [a,b])$. But is $V$ actually the space of symmetric functions in $L^2([a,b]\times [a,b])$? If not, is there any other useful way to charecterize $V$?

$f:=\sum_{m,n}a_{n,m}\phi_n\otimes\phi_m$ is symmetric iff it is also equal to $\sum_{m,n}a_{n,m}\phi_m\otimes\phi_n$, i.e. iff
$$\forall(m,n)\quad a_{m,n}=a_{n,m}.$$ $f\in V$ is more restrictive.

Ah yes, I was actually about to suggest that myself, one can look at the difference of f(x,y) and f(y,x) expanded in the product basis and we know it must be the zero element from which the coefficient relationship you display follows.
Thank you!

But that doesn't solve your final question.

No: with my notations, (again) $a_{m,n}-a_{n,m}=0$, and this doesn't imply $f\in V$. EDIT: indeed. I think we can delete these 2 last comments.

Since it’s already been made clear that $V$ is not the space of symmetric functions, let me also point out that $V$ does not really admit any useful characterization because it is dependent on the choice of the ONB $\phi_n$. For example, $(\phi_1 + \phi_2)^{\otimes 2}$ is not in $V$, but if your ONB contains $\frac{\phi_1 + \phi_2}{\sqrt{2}}$, then it would be.
